# perl gnuplot is is possible to pass dataset as array?

Tags: perl, charts, package, gnuplot

Consider this example :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Chart::Gnuplot;

# Initiate the chart object
my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    output => "plotStyle_1.png",
);

# A line
my $lines = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    func  => "cos(x)",
    style => "lines",
    title => "Plot a line",
);

# Points
my $points = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    func  => "sin(x)",
    style => "points",
    title => "Plot points",
);

# Points on a line
my $linespoints = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    func  => "-atan(x)",
    style => "linespoints",
    title => "Plot points on a line",
);

# Plot the graph
$chart->plot2d($lines, $points, $linespoints);
```

What I want is to push the 3 objects in plot2d (last line in code) to an array and call it this way:

```
$chart->plot2d(@array);
```

this is the implementation of plot2d

```
    sub plot2d
{
    my ($self, @dataSet) = @_;
    &_setChart($self, \@dataSet);

    my $plotString = join(', ', map {$_->_thaw($self)} @dataSet);
    open(GPH, ">>$self->{_script}") || confess("Can't write $self->{_script}");
    print GPH "\nplot $plotString\n";
    close(GPH);

    # Generate image file
    &execute($self);
    return($self);
}
```

**Is it possible to call it with array as parameter ? **
please note that im not expert in perl I can't understand the implementation of plot2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just do it. In your specific case, this would be:

```
my @datasets;
push @datasets, $lines;
push @datasets, $points;
push @datasets, $linespoints;

$chart->plot2d(@datasets);
```